# Google Apps Script: Copy and paste selected cell to another sheet, then delete from source

Tags: google-apps-script

I am completely new to google apps script - any help is appreciated!

I have a spreadsheet called Dismissal. On this spreadsheet, there is a tab called "Student Names" and another called "Check Out". I am wondering if there is a script to copy whichever cell is selected from the Student Names tab and paste it to the first empty row in column A of the Check Out tab - and then delete the cell from the source (the Student Names tab), or at least clear the contents of the cell on the source.

Please let me know if you need any more details. Thank you so much --

Comment: About `copy whichever cell is selected from the Student Names tab`, in this case, how is the cell selected? And also, how do you want to run the script?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets. If you need further help, please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts for answers from this site as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

#### Copy Student Name to Check Out

```
function copyNameToCheckOut() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Student Names");
  const dsh = ss.getSheetByName("Check Out");
  sh.getActiveCell().copyTo(dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1));
  sh.getActiveCell().clearContent();
}
```